# How to append slug to root path with history API?

Tags: javascript, history, slug

**Current URL is**

```
example.com/properties/one/
```

By Calling history.pushState

```
history.pushState('', '', `search/two`);
```

I got appended slug

```
example.com/properties/one/search/two
```

**Expected result:**

```
example.com/search/two
```

The question is how to achieve `search/two` slug be appended to the root path?

Comment: What if you include a forward slash at the start? `'/search/two'`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks, it works with forwarding slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @evolutionxbox, adding a forwarding slash solved the problem.

```
history.pushState('', '', `/search/two`);
```